# Oracle guid to other table

Tags: c#, oracle, guid, save, byte

At the moment I'm writing a small conversion program, it will convert the primary key strategy to the using of GUIDs in stead of integers. This is a simple client induced requirement and I can't change that.

I've added a substitute pk candidate of the RAW(16) to every table in the database and filled each record with a SYS_GUID().
I did the same for the FKs, I added a substitute column for each FK.
Now I'm in the process of linking the FKs to their PKs, by querying the parent table I get the  guid/new key for the specific row, after that I want to insert into the substitute candidate FK in the child table.

Somewhat like this:

```
sqlString = "SELECT PK FROM " + t+ " WHERE " + fkcol+ " = " + childValue;
OracleDataReader guidReader = GetDataReader(sqlString);

while (guidReader.Read())
{
    sqlString = "UPDATE T SET FK = " + guidReader["PK"];
}
```

Debugging this sqlString gets me the following value:

> UPDATE SIS_T_USER SET FK_C_EMPLOYEE_ID
>   = System.Byte[]

Now, how do I go forth and save this as a nice guid in my oracle database?

EDit how:

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sqlString, this.oracleConnection);
                                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                OracleParameter op1 = new OracleParameter("guid", OracleDbType.Raw);
                                op1.Value = guidReader["PK"];
                                command.Parameters.Add(op1);
                                try
                                {
                                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch (OracleException oex)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to update: {0}", oex.Message);
                                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do this all on `Oracle` side?

```
MERGE
INTO    sis_t_user s
USING   employee e
ON      (s.integer_fk = e.integer_pk)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     s.guid_fk = e.guid_pk
```

Comment: I don't want to elaborate too much on it, but eventually I need to toss around guids anyway, so sooner or later the same question will emerge, with a different coating. Though your solution is fine, it doesnt suffice for (our specific)  future needs. I wouldn't have asked the question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
sqlString = "UPDATE T SET FK = '" + (new Guid((byte[])guidReader["PK"])).ToString() + "'";
```

Basically, you just need to create guid from bytes and then convert it to string.
There is Guid constructor that allows it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3(v=VS.100).aspx.

Comment: Could you show how the update should look like? I thought you need sth like UPDATE SIS_T_USER SET FK_C_EMPLOYEE_ID = '33b386b2-bf1d-42be-9110-c688cb8c8afc'

Comment: I made some changes, in stead of this naive approach im using a paramterized query.
works much easier